# Question on solution of Casella and Berger Exercise 9.10: Showing that $Q(t,\theta)$ is a pivot

Tags: distributions, inference, density-function, pivot

My question concerns Exercise 9.10 of *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger: On page 428 the authors say

> In general, suppose the pdf of a statistic $T$, $f(t|\theta)$, can be expressed in the form
> $$ f(t|\theta) = g(Q(t,\theta)) \left| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} Q(t,\theta)\right| $$
>
> for some function $g$ and some monotone function $Q$ (monotone in $t$ for each $\theta$). Then Theorem 2.1.5 can be used to show that $Q(T,\theta)$ is a pivot (see Exercise 9.10).

Exercise 9.10 just asks for a proof of this statement.

For reference, here is Theorem 2.1.5 (slightly paraphrased):

> **Theorem 2.1.5** Let $X$ have pdf $f_X(x)$ and let $Y = g(X)$, where $g$ is a monotone function. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the support of $f_X$ and let $\mathcal{Y} = g(\mathcal{X})$. Suppose that $f_X(x)$ is continuous on $\mathcal{X}$ and that $g^{-1}(y)$ has a continuous derivative on $\mathcal{Y}$. Then the pdf of $Y$ is given by
> $$ f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) \right|, \quad y \in \mathcal{Y}. $$

I got a bit stuck on this problem so I perused online and came across the following solution:
[image]

I'm a bit confused here. Specifically, how was the following line obtained?
$$ f_Y(y) = g(y) \left| \frac{d Q^{-1}(y;\theta)}{dt}\right|^{-1} \left| \frac{d Q^{-1}(y;\theta)}{dt}\right|  $$
obtained?

**Edit 5/7/22**: Thanks to @whuber for the excellent proof. However, I'm still confused about why the following argument leads to a seeming contradiction. To hopefully make things clearer, I introduce the following notation:

- Let $\Theta$ be the parameter space.
- Let $\mathbb{S}^n (\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the sample space for a random sample of size $n$.
- Let $s: \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{T}$ where $\mathcal{T} := s(\mathbb{S}^n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.
- Let $T = s(\mathbf{X})$ and let $f_T(t|\theta)$ be the pdf of $T$.
- Let $q: \mathcal{T} \times \Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is monotone in $t$ for each $\theta \in \Theta$.
- For each $\theta \in \Theta$, let $q_{\theta}: \mathcal{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $q_{\theta}(t) := q(t,\theta)$ for all $t \in \mathcal{T}$.
- Let $g: q(\mathcal{T} \times \Theta) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a fixed function.
- For each $\theta \in \Theta$, let $Y_{\theta} = q_{\theta}(T)$ and let $f_{Y}(y|\theta)$ be the pdf of $Y_{\theta}$.

We are given that
$$  f_{T}(t|\theta) = g(q(t,\theta)) \left| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} q(t,\theta) \right| \qquad \forall (t,\theta) \in \mathcal{T} \times \Theta  \hspace{3cm}  $$

or equivalently,
$$ f_T(t|\theta) = g(q_{\theta}(t)) \left| \frac{d}{dt}q_{\theta}(t) \right| \qquad \forall (t,\theta) \in \mathcal{T} \times \Theta. \hspace{3cm} (1) $$

Now since $Y_{\theta} = q_{\theta}(T)$ where $q_{\theta}$ is monotone (by assumption), $q_{\theta}$ has a well-defined inverse $q_{\theta}^{-1}$. Then applying Theorem 2.1.5 and (1), we obtain

\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y|\theta) &= f_T(q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)\right| && (\text{Change of Vars Theorem}) \\[5pt]
&= \left(g(q_{\theta}(q_{\theta}^{-1}(y))) \left|\frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}(q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)) \right| \right)  \left| \frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)\right| && (\text{Applying (1)})     \\[5pt]
&= \left( g(y) \left|\frac{d}{dy}(y) \right| \right)  \left| \frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)\right|  && (\text{Simplifying}) \\[5pt]
&= g(y) \left| \frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}^{-1}(y)\right|. && (\text{Simplifying})
\end{align*}

But @whuber's answer shows that $f_Y \equiv g$, so we would need $\left|\frac{d}{dy} q_{\theta}^{-1}(y) \right| \equiv 1$. But this appears to be a contradiction because there was no such restriction on $q_{\theta}$ to begin with...where in the above argument did I go wrong?

Any insights, or alternative solutions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which is the "first equality"?

Comment: @whuber: $f_Y(y) = g(y) \left| \frac{d Q^{-1}(y;\theta)}{dt}\right|^{-1} \left| \frac{d Q^{-1}(y;\theta)}{dt}\right|$

Comment: That's a standard formula for changing the variable of a density (making allowances for a truly abominable notation--it's discouraging to see a text try to differentiate a function of $y$ and $\theta$ with respect to $t$!).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220 for why it's needed (and what it means) and see any post that mentions [probability element](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22probability+element%22) for examples.

Comment: @whuber: I am familiar with the change of variables formula. I realized that my solution attempt was nonsense, so I've edited the post! I'm still confused though on how the line I mentioned was obtained...

Comment: You might do better by changing the notation to something that is less ambiguous and more rigorous and then re-doing the calculation.  I think the notation is really interfering with both the algebra and the understanding.

Comment: @whuber: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are the steps in my work (in the edited answer) incorrect? And which notation is ambiguous?

Comment: It's all ambiguous and inconsistent.  For instance, sometimes you drop the "$|\theta$" from $f;$ it's unclear what expressions are functions and which are being kept constant; there's no distinction made in your notation between partial derivatives and total derivatives; and it's even unclear what substitutions or definitions are being made--you seem to define $y$ in terms of a function of itself, for instance.  All this can easily lead to hard-to-detect mistakes.

Comment: Atrocious, indeed.

Comment: I hope my new proof with added notation clears up the ambiguity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an effort to clarify the notation I have arrived at an equivalent demonstration based on the distribution functions rather than the densities.  Let's see how this plays out.

---

**What I aim to achieve is a notation that is at once rigorous and clear.**  The methods I use include

1. Make consistent typographic distinctions among random variables, distribution functions, densities, and parameters.  I have chosen a conventional system:

   - $\mathbf T$ is a random variable.
   - $F$ is a distribution function.
   - $f$ is a generic function, including a density function.
   - $\theta$ is a parameter.
   - $t$ is a real variable.

   This convention offers no typographic distinction between functions and variables, but the "$f(t)$" notation makes their roles clear.
2. Distinguish functions, such as $f,$ from their values at arguments like $f(t).$  Thus, when $f$ is a real-valued function, $f(t)$ is *not* a function: it's a real number.
3. Make the differential elements, like $\mathrm{d}t,$ explicitly appear in expressions involving densities, because these are essential to transforming them correctly.
4. Name parameters like $\theta$ explicitly where it will help, but make it clear they are not going to be differentiated or integrated: they are just along to designate members of a family of distributions.  To this end I subscript them to get them out of the way.

---

Let $f_{\mathbf T;\theta}$ be the pdf of the statistic $\mathbf T$ when the parameter is $\theta.$  This means $f_{\mathbf T;\theta}$ is the derivative of the distribution function of $\mathbf T,$ or equivalently

$$\mathrm{d} F_{\mathbf T;\theta}(t) = f_{\mathbf T;\theta}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Suppose that for each parameter value $\theta$ the probability element on the right hand side can be expressed in the form

$$f_{\mathbf T;\theta}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = g(q_\theta(t))\, \mathrm{d}q_\theta(t) = \mathrm{d}\left(G\circ q_\theta\right)(t)\tag{*}$$

for a family of functions $q_\theta$ and a *fixed* function $G$ with derivative $G^\prime = g.$ (Notice that changing $G$ by subtracting any constant value will not alter this relationship with $g.$  We will exploit this at the end.)

The preceding sets of equations give

$$\mathrm{d}F_{\mathbf T;\theta} = \mathrm{d}\left(G\circ q_\theta\right)(t).$$

**I wish to emphasize the clarity and simplicity of this equation,** *because it is the crux of the matter:* it says the family of densities $\mathrm d F_\theta$ is obtained by transforming a *fixed* distribution $G$ by a family of functions $\{q_\theta\}.$  This insight, which is suggested by the new notation, was buried in the distracting, rococo details of the original statement of the theorem.

Integrating gives

$$F_{\mathbf T;\theta}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \mathrm{d}F_{\mathbf T;\theta}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^t \mathrm{d}\left(G\circ q_\theta\right)(x) = G(q_\theta(t)) - \lim_{s\to-\infty} G(q_\theta(s)).$$

Write $C_\theta$ for that (annoying) limit on the right hand side.  Later it will go away, but only after we make some additional assumptions.

*We have enough information to compute the distribution of $\mathbf Y = q_\theta(\mathbf T)$ provided each $q_\theta$ is monotonically increasing.*  (It would be overkill, although strictly speaking required, to write $\mathbf Y = \mathbf Y_\theta.$  For that matter we should be writing $\mathbf T = \mathbf T_\theta,$ but I hope you agree all this subscripting would be redundant: it's enough to subscript their distribution and density functions with $\theta.$)

This assumption on the $q_\theta$ implies there exists a corresponding family of monotonic right inverse functions $q_\theta^{-1}$ for which

$$q_\theta(q^{-1}_\theta(y)) = y$$ for all $y.$

Invoke the definition of the distribution function twice to deduce

$$\begin{aligned}
F_{\mathbf Y;\theta}(y) & := \Pr(q_\theta(\mathbf T)\le y) \\
&= \Pr(\mathbf T \le q_\theta^{-1}(y))\\
& =: F_{\mathbf T;\theta}(q_\theta^{-1}(y)) \\
&= G(q_\theta(q_\theta^{-1}(y)) - C_\theta \\
&= G(y) - C_\theta.
\end{aligned}$$

This implies $C_\theta$ does not depend on $\theta,$ because (for instance)

$$0 = \lim_{y\to -\infty} F_{Y;\theta}(y) = \lim_{y\to-\infty} G(y) - C_\theta$$

shows $C_\theta = \lim_{y\to-\infty} G(y) =: C,$ say.  We may therefore replace $G$ by the function $G-C$  without changing any of the foregoing calculations and conclude that

> The distribution function of $q_\theta(\mathbf T)$ is $G$ no matter what value the parameter $\theta$ might have.

That's what it means to be a "pivot."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed proof and explanation! I will take some time to digest this. Also, I've edited my post with a new proof which hopefully makes things more rigorous and less ambiguous.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at your proof--it's very nice and makes sense! Thanks for taking the time to write up the details. I have one remaining question: where did I go wrong in my proof attempt? (I just edited my proof because I realized the previous version was nonsense. It should hopefully be less non-nonsensical now.)  It seems to be flawed, and I would very much like to know where flaw lies.

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation, the solution writer applied the change of variable formula to change from a density in $t$ to one in $Y = Q(t; \theta)$, as well as applying the given information about the format of $f_Y$. The complete statement of the change of variable formula can be found in Theorem 2.1.5 of Casella & Berger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am familiar with the change of variables formula. I'm still not seeing how the formula leads to $f_Y(y) = g(y)$. Could you spell out the details?